# " - Stack Exchange" suffix no longer displayed in page title on many secondary sites

Tags: discussion, site-name

I'm finding that the `- Stack Exchange` suffix is no longer displayed in the page title on many secondary sites.  For example, "Photography - Stack Exchange" is now shown as "[Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/)", and "Mi Yodeya - Stack Exchange" is shown as "[Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/)".

Is this change intentional?  If so, why was this change made?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because the site is graduated.  If you notice, beta sites such as [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) still include `Stack Exchange` as part of the title.

I suppose this is to give it the impression of it being its own website.  It is not really a StackExchange incubator anymore and has a large audience with much activity like [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) and [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com/).