# Why do some sites have an extra "SE" in their names?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, site-name

In the homepage of Data SE, I see that some sites have an extra "SE" in the name, while the rest don't have. Is this an intention or just a kind of bug? 
[image: image description]
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

At first I thought that this is a duplicate of [“ - Stack Exchange” suffix no longer displayed in page title on many secondary sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132457/260800), but as you can see not every beta sites have the suffix.

Comment: If I had to guess, since all of those sites are in Beta, it's simply that whoever created the proposal called it that... and the name stuck. When you create a proposal in Area 51, you pick the name of the site. If it never gets changed, then it stays.

Comment: [Well, I don't think so](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/earth-science?referrer=JPpwa3Xpfr6hnta5OH8wmA2)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just an issue with tidying up the metadata, yeah (so a bug). When I have time I'm going to determine what the easiest way is to keep the site names [consistent and in sync](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261517/sede-should-pick-up-on-changes-to-community-metadata) so it's no longer a problem in the future.

The expected behaviour is for "Stack Exchange" to be removed from all of them, with the obvious exception of this site, Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: erm, don't you answer in that question as well?

Comment: Well, here I could confirm that the current behaviour is a bug, since you weren't 100% sure why this was happening. The other report was unquestionably a bug, so I'll wait to actually fix it to answer there.